# Unable to empty stored string of a variable after textEditingController.clear()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build an animated search widget. When I use this widget in a different screen, I am storing the text of the textEditingController `searchController` of this search widget in a String variable `searchText`. The `searchText` variable is updating fine when I assign it the value of the `searchController.text` during the `onChanged` function call of the widget. However, when I click on the icon button of the search widget, I am clearing the `searchController` but it is not updating the value of the `searchText` variable. What I understand is that the clear() action is not a part of the onChanged() call.

How do I update the value of the `searchText` variable when the `searchController.clear()` is called in the onPressed call of the icon button? I am implementing Tween animation in the onPressed function of the icon button, so I am not sure if I can/should be using it to update the value of the string variable.

**My Code**

*girls_screen.dart*

```
import 'package:animation_search_bar/animation_search_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/model/girls.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/screens/gender.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/screens/girls_cart.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/screens/search_widget.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/screens/selected_girl_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';

import '../global_variables/global_variables.dart';

int distance = 15;
int age = 25;
String sortCriterion = "distance";
bool isSingle = false;
bool isSerious = false;
int count = 0;
String searchText = "";

List<Girls> allGirls = [
  Girls("Reshmita", 25, 33, "Married", "Serious"),
  Girls("Ankita", 17, 26, "Single", "Serious"),
  Girls("Rupali", 42, 28, "Single", "Casual"),
  Girls("Monica", 50, 24, "Single", "Casual"),
  Girls("Sakshi", 9, 27, "Married", "Casual"),
];

List<Girls> filteredGirlsbyDistance = [];
List<Girls> filteredGirlsbyAge = [];
List<Girls> filteredGirls = [];
List<Girls> filteredGirlsbySerious = [];
List<Girls> filteredGirlsbySingle = [];

//List<Girls> girlsCart = [];

void addGirlToCart(Girls girl) {
  girlsCart.add(girl);
  cartValue = cartValue + girl.age;
}

void removeGirlsfromCart(Girls girl) {
  girlsCart.remove(girl);
  cartValue = cartValue - girl.age;
}

String selectedGirlName = "";
int? selectedGirlDistance;

void populateFilteredGirls(int dis, int ag) {
  filteredGirlsbyDistance.clear();
  filteredGirlsbyAge.clear();
  filteredGirlsbySingle.clear();
  filteredGirlsbySerious.clear();
  filteredGirls.clear();
  //int len = filteredGirls.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < allGirls.length; i++) {
    if (allGirls[i].distance <= dis) {
      filteredGirlsbyDistance.add(allGirls[i]);
    }
  }
  filteredGirls = filteredGirlsbyDistance;
  for (int i = 0; i < filteredGirls.length; i++) {
    if (filteredGirls[i].age <= ag) {
      filteredGirlsbyAge.add(filteredGirls[i]);
    }
  }
  filteredGirls = filteredGirlsbyAge;
  //len = filteredGirls.length;
  if (isSingle == true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filteredGirls.length; i++) {
      if (filteredGirls[i].status.toLowerCase() == "single") {
        filteredGirlsbySingle.add(filteredGirls[i]);
      }
    }
    filteredGirls = filteredGirlsbySingle;
  }
  if (isSerious == true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < filteredGirls.length; i++) {
      if (filteredGirls[i].lookingFor.toLowerCase() == "serious") {
        filteredGirlsbySerious.add(filteredGirls[i]);
      }
    }
    filteredGirls = filteredGirlsbySerious;
  }
  //filteredGirls = filteredGirls.toSet().toList();
}

class GirlsResultGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  GirlsResultGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GirlsResultGrid> createState() => _GirlsResultGridState();
}

class _GirlsResultGridState extends State<GirlsResultGrid> {
  //late final GlobalKey<AnimationLimiterState> _key

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: AnimationLimiter(
          key: ValueKey("list $count"),
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
            childAspectRatio: 2,
            children: List.generate(filteredGirls.length, (index) {
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                columnCount: 2,
                position: index,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                child: SlideAnimation(
                  child: FadeInAnimation(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: InkWell(
                        child: const Icon(Icons.girl_outlined),
                        onTap: () {
                          removeGirlsfromCart(filteredGirls[index]);
                        },
                      ),
                      trailing: InkWell(
                        child: Text("${filteredGirls[index].distance} km away"),
                        onTap: () {
                          addGirlToCart(filteredGirls[index]);
                        },
                      ),
                      title: Text("${filteredGirls[index].name}"),
                      subtitle: Text(
                          "${filteredGirls[index].age} years old, ${filteredGirls[index].status}, ${filteredGirls[index].lookingFor}"),
                      onTap: () {
                        // setState(() {
                        //   selectedGirlName = filteredGirls[index].name;
                        //   selectedGirlDistance = filteredGirls[index].distance;
                        // });
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SelectedGirlDetails(
                                      girl: filteredGirls[index],
                                    )));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
            //itemCount: ,
            //itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GirlsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  GirlsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GirlsScreen> createState() => _GirlsScreenState();
}

class _GirlsScreenState extends State<GirlsScreen> {
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  void changeDistance(double num) {
    setState(() {
      distance = num.round();

      populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
      count++;
    });
  }

  void changeAgeLimit(double a) {
    setState(() {
      age = a.round();
      populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
      count++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //filteredGirls = allGirls;
    distance = 20;
    age = 28;
    sortCriterion = "distance";
    isSingle = false;
    isSerious = false;

    (sortCriterion == "distance")
        ? allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance))
        : allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.age.compareTo(b.age));
    populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
  }

  // Widget buildResult(BuildContext context) {

  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),

          // ElevatedButton(
          //     onPressed: () {
          //       Navigator.push(context,
          //           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GenderScreen()));
          //     },
          //     child: Text("Go to Gender Screen")),
          // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(30)),
          SearchWidget(
            searchController: searchTextEditingController,
            onChanged: (p0) {
              setState(() {
                searchText = p0;
              });
            },
          ),
          Text("Girl searched is: $searchText"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Set max distance"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Slider(
            min: 1.0,
            max: 100.0,
            divisions: 100,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.orange,
            label: 'Set distance value',
            value: distance.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              changeDistance(value);
            },
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Current distance is $distance kms"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Set max age"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Slider(
            min: 18.0,
            max: 60.0,
            divisions: 42,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.orange,
            label: 'Set age limit',
            value: age.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              changeAgeLimit(value);
            },
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Age limit is $age years"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Sort by:"),

          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.5)),
          ListTile(
            //minLeadingWidth: 30,
            title: Text("Age"),
            leading: Radio(
              value: "age",
              groupValue: sortCriterion,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sortCriterion = value.toString();
                  allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.age.compareTo(b.age));
                  populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
                  count++;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.5)),
          ListTile(
            //minLeadingWidth: 30,
            title: Text("Distance"),
            leading: Radio(
              value: "distance",
              groupValue: sortCriterion,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sortCriterion = value.toString();
                  allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance));
                  populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
                  count++;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Is Single?"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.5)),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isSingle = !isSingle;
                populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
                count++;
              });
            },
            child: (isSingle == false)
                ? Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank)
                : Icon(Icons.check_box),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),
          Text("Is Serious?"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.5)),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isSerious = !isSerious;
                populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
                count++;
              });
            },
            child: (isSerious == false)
                ? Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank)
                : Icon(Icons.check_box),
          ),

          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),

          //buildResult(context),
          GirlsResultGrid(),

          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(25)),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GirlsCart()));
              },
              child: Text("Go to Girls Cart")),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(25)),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

*search_widget.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(String)? onChanged;
  TextEditingController? searchController;
  VoidCallback? onTap;
  SearchWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.onChanged,
    this.searchController,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchWidget> createState() => _SearchWidgetState();
}

class _SearchWidgetState extends State<SearchWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<double> animation;
  late AnimationController animController;
  bool isForward = false;
  //TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    animController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );

    final curvedAnimation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animController, curve: Curves.easeOutExpo);

    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 150).animate(curvedAnimation)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: Container(
          width: 220,
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: animation.value,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 5),
                  child: TextField(
                    //autofocus: true,
                    controller: widget.searchController,
                    onChanged: widget.onChanged,
                    cursorColor: Colors.white54,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54, fontSize: 12),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Search girls...",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 53,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  borderRadius: animation.value > 1
                      ? BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                        )
                      : BorderRadius.circular(50),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (!isForward) {
                      animController.forward();
                      isForward = true;
                    } else if (isForward &&
                        widget.searchController!.text != "") {
                      widget.searchController!.clear();
                    } else {
                      animController.reverse();
                      isForward = false;
                    }
                  },
                  icon: (!isForward)
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.white54,
                        )
                      : Icon(
                          Icons.close_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white54,
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Video for reference**
https://vimeo.com/735839961

Answer (score 0):

Realized the solution. I added a Voidcallback parameter to the widget, which is called once the cross icon button is tapped on.

In *girls_screen.dart*

```
SearchWidget(
            searchController: searchTextEditingController,
            onChanged: (p0) {
              setState(() {
                searchText = p0;
              });
            },
            onTap: () {
              if (searchText != "") {
                setState(() {
                  searchText = "";
                });
              }
            },
          ),
```

In *search_widget.dart*

```
child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (!isForward) {
                      animController.forward();
                      isForward = true;
                    } else if (isForward &&
                        widget.searchController!.text != "") {
                      widget.searchController!.clear();
                    } else {
                      animController.reverse();
                      isForward = false;
                    }
                    widget.onTap!();
                  },
```